# Unicode-math upright symbols

Tags: unicode-math

In the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package, what is the difference between `\mupalpha` and `\upalpha`? What is the purpose of the `m` prefix?

Comment: I can't find a reference to either `\upalpha` or `\mupalpha` in the user guide of the `unicode-math` package. In contrast, `\mupalpha` *is* mentioned in the user guide of the [unimath-symbols](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math) package. Is that maybe the package you're thinking of?

Comment: The `unicode-math` package website provides the document "List of sym­bols de­fined by the pack­age". This document lists `\mupalpha`, but not `\upalpha`. Both symbols work in XeTex.

Comment: The "List of sym­bols de­fined by the [unicode-math] pack­age" provided on the package's website is indeed the same document as the user guide of the `unimath-symbols` package. :-) I'd say that `\m` is a generic prefix for math-symbols; the following variant glyphs of `\alpha` are defined: `\mupalpha`, `\mitalpha`, `\mbfalpha`, `\mbfitalpha`, `\mbfsansalpha`, and `\mbfitsansalpha. However, not all math fonts provide all of these glyph variants. The various TeX formats (Plain, LaTeX, etc) may provide additional macros that point directly to these glyphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the slow reply `:)`

This might not be documented particularly well. `\mupalpha` refers to an input character, and `\upalpha` essentially refers to an output character (which is usually what a user is interested in).

If you take a look in `unicode-math-table.tex` you see that `\mupalpha` is listed as the definition for the mathematical upright alpha:

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"003B1}{\mupalpha                 }{\mathalpha}{small alpha, greek}%
```

If you then write `\show\mupalpha` in a document you will receive (at time of writing, this might change in the future):

```
> \mupalpha=the character α.
```

The upright/italic nature of Greek symbols in the OUTPUT is controlled by unicode-math options like `math-style=upright`. I.e., writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\mupalpha$ or $α$
\end{document}
```

will result in two upright alphas — the two input forms (command or char) are equivalent.

In contrast, `\upalpha` is a long-standing LaTeX command to produce, you guessed it, an upright alpha. In fact, it is defined internally as `\symup{\alpha}`. So regardless of `math-style` and so on, writing `\upalpha` will ALWAYS give you an upright alpha.